# How to map VM to internal network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, openstack

I have a Dell's Machine with High on Resources like (32 GB RAM, 24 cores of CPU and 5 TB of Disk Space).

I have installed Openstack(devstack) on this Machine which has Ubuntu installed on it and has IP address 10.10.1.3.

This machine is in our local network , means i can ssh directly to this big machine from my laptop if i am in same network.

Now i have created a virtual machine instance using openstack and it has Ubuntu on it and it has IP address 10.10.0.3.

Now i want to access this virtual machine directly from my laptop like i access the big machine.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vm (let's call it "instance") is on a internal network (tenant/project network) what you need is a FIP (floating IP) from your external network so you can assign that FIP to your openstack instance. Also ensure your security groups allow ssh to your vm !.

I have some questions here so I can help you a better way:

- Do you have an external network already created (flat or vlan based) ?.
- The vm is using a tenant/project internal (gre/vxlan) network ?
- Did you create a router in your tenant, which is using the external network for external access ?.
- The aforementioned router is already connected to your internal network ?.

Comment: Thanks @tigerlinux for this quick response.

Comment: Here are my answers:Do you have an external network already created (flat or vlan based) ?.
The vm is using a tenant/project internal (gre/vxlan) network ?
Did you create a router in your tenant, which is using the external network for external access ?.
The aforementioned router is already connected to your internal network ?.

Comment: Ehhh... where are the answers ?. I only see my own questions :-)

Comment: Here are the answers:
Do you have an external network already created (flat or vlan based) ?.
==Tenant has acees to internet and thus the instance also.i have not created any network.
The vm is using a tenant/project internal (gre/vxlan) network ?
==Yes, i guess.
Did you create a router in your tenant, which is using the external network for external access ?.
==No. i have not created any router , it is managed by openstack.
The aforementioned router is already connected to your internal network ?.
==Not Sure.

Comment: Sorry.. I was unable to edit comment after i pressed enter...:(

Comment: Ok, if you instance (vm) is on the tenant network, you should be able to allocate "floating IP's" from the external network (secutiry section in your horizon dashboard), and assign it to the instance. Also, ensure there is a security group (or create it) which allows incomming ssh and incomming icmp so you can both ping and ssh to your instance. Note that you need to ssh your instance using the FIP, not the IP assigned from the internal/tenant network.